# ASP.NET EF Core Health Check Returns nothing but 200 status

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, health-check

I'm currently implementing a health check on my Identity ASP.NET Core 3.1 project using PostgreSQL and EntifyFramework Core under Docker container.

This are the nuget packages installed in my project

- Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.3
- Npgsql.EntityFrameworkCore.PostgreSQL 3.1.3
- Microsoft.Extensions.Diagnostics.HealthChecks.EntityFrameworkCore
  3.1.3
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.3

Here is my Startup.cs class

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Identity:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddDbContextCheck<IdentityContext>("Database");

    services.AddControllers();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{
    app.UseHealthChecks("/health");
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();
    });   
}
```

Everything works fine, I am getting a Healthy response with 200 status code by accessing the /health endpoint until I intentionally stop the PostgreSQL container in my docker.

I am expecting to receive 503 status code with an Unhealthy response from /health but instead a got a blank response with 200 status code

Here's a snapshot of the result from postman
[image]

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution to this? Facing the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

I think your "Database" check not called when you request url "/health".
Try register HealthCheck with tag.
Then define enpoint with this tag.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => options.UseNpgsql(Configuration["Identity:ConnectionString"]));

    services.AddHealthChecks()
            .AddDbContextCheck<IdentityContext>("Database",tags: new[] { "live" });

    services.AddControllers();
}


public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
{       
    app.UseHttpsRedirection();

    app.UseRouting();

    app.UseAuthentication();
    app.UseAuthorization();

    app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
    {
       endpoints.MapControllers();

       endpoints.MapHealthChecks("/health/live", new HealthCheckOptions()
            {
                Predicate = (check) => check.Tags.Contains("live") 
            });
    });   
}
```

You can read about health check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/health-checks?view=aspnetcore-3.1)